# Is there a way to combine two Scala TableDrivenPropertyChecks Tables into one?

Tags: scala, scalatest, table-driven

I want to combine two tables: one containing inputs and the other containing expected outputs into a single table that I can run through ScalaTest's `TableDrivenProperyChecks` framework. Below is essentially what I'm going for:

```
import org.scalatest.prop.TableDrivenPropertyChecks._

val inputs = Table(
    ("a", "b"),  // First tuple defines column names
    (  1,   2),  // Subsequent tuples define the data
    ( -1,   2),
)
    
val expectedOutputs = Table(
    ("addition", "subtraction"),  // First tuple defines column names
    (3,   -1),  // Subsequent tuples define the data
    (1,   -3),
)
    
forAll(inputs zip expectedOutputs) { (a, b, add, sub) =>
  sumFn(a, b) should equal (add)
  diffFn(a, b) should equal (sub)
}
```

I know that conventionally tests define the expected values in the same table as the inputs, but I find that to be confusing especially when tuples get long. This feels more elegant if possible.

I see that the `org.scalatest.prop.TableFor2` extends `scala.IndexedSeq`, but I can't get it to play nicely with `forAll`. Basically the `inputs zip expectedOutputs` thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using tuples with many elements could be hard to read. It becomes harder in a collection. [Table-driven property checks](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/table_driven_property_checks) helps you to avoid duplicated code when you need to write the same tests with different values. You could have the expected output in the table, but I don't think it will be easier to read or maintain.

The article [Knoldus - Table Driven Testing in Scala](https://blog.knoldus.com/table-driven-testing-in-scala/) have a good example where instead of having the expected output in the table, it write tests that return the same value with different inputs:

> ###### Order.scala (model)
>
> ```scala
> case class Order(quantity: Int, price: Int) {
>   def isEmptyOrder: Boolean = quantity == 0 && price == 0
> }
> ```
>
> ###### OrderValidation.scala (logic)
>
> ```scala
> object OrderValidation {
>
>   def validateOrder(order: Order): Boolean =
>     order.isEmptyOrder || (validatePrice(order.price) && validateQuantity(order.quantity))
>
>   private def validatePrice(p: Int): Boolean = p > 0
>   private def validateQuantity(q: Int): Boolean = q > 0
>
> }
> ```
>
> ###### OrderValidationTableDrivenSpec.scala (test)
>
> ```scala
> import org.scalatest.FreeSpec
> import org.scalatest._
> import org.scalatest.prop.TableDrivenPropertyChecks
>
> class OrderValidationTableDrivenSpec extends FreeSpec with TableDrivenPropertyChecks with Matchers {
>
>   "Order Validation" - {
>     "should validate and return false if" - {
>       val orders = Table(
>         ("statement"                        , "order"),
>         ("price is negative"                , Order(quantity = 10, price = -2)),
>         ("quantity is negative"             , Order(quantity = -10, price = 2)),
>         ("price and quantity are negative"  , Order(quantity = -10, price = -2))
>       )
>
>       forAll(orders) {(statement, invalidOrder) =>
>         s"$statement" in {
>           OrderValidation.validateOrder(invalidOrder) shouldBe false
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

In this case, the table just have the name of the case that is being validated and then the input value, which is the `Order` in this case.

You can see the same approaach in the gist [davidallsopp - PropertyTests.scala](https://gist.github.com/davidallsopp/60d7474a1fe8dc9b1f2d):

> ```scala
> class Example extends PropSpec with PropertyChecks with ShouldMatchers {
>
>   val examples =
>     Table(
>       "set",
>       BitSet.empty,
>       HashSet.empty[Int],
>       TreeSet.empty[Int])
>
>   // table-driven
>   property("an empty Set should have size 0") {
>     //forAll(examples) { set => set.size should be(0) }
>     forAll(examples) { _.size should be(0) }
>   }
>
>   // table-driven, expecting exceptions
>   property("invoking head on an empty set should produce NoSuchElementException") {
>     forAll(examples) { set =>
>       a[NoSuchElementException] should be thrownBy { set.head }
>     }
>   }
>
>   // table-driven, expecting exceptions, with an alternative syntax
>   property("again, invoking head on an empty set should produce NoSuchElementException") {
>     forAll(examples) { set =>
>       evaluating { set.head } should produce[NoSuchElementException]
>     }
>   }
>
>   // A 2-column table
>   val colours = Table(
>     ("Name", "Colour"), // First tuple is the title row
>     ("r", Color.RED),
>     ("g", Color.GREEN),
>     ("b", Color.BLUE))
>
>   property("colours") {
>     forAll(colours) { (name: String, colour: Color) =>
>       colour.toString should include(s"$name=255") // e.g. java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]
>     }
>   }
>
>   // A bit more concise with a case statement (don't need explicit types)
>   property("colours2") {
>     forAll(colours) { case (name, colour) => colour.toString should include(s"$name=255") } // e.g. java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Each test case have different inputs but all of them expect the same output.

---

From the example provided in your question

```scala
val inputs = Table(
    ("a", "b"),
    (  1,   2),
    ( -1,   2),
)

forAll(inputs) { (a, b) =>
  sumFn(a, b) should equal (a + b)
  diffFn(a, b) should equal (a - b)
}
```

It doesn't make sense to use **Table-driven property checks** (I think it was just a dummy example to avoid complexity). If your real case is similar to something like that, it could be better to validate the logic of your code using [Generator-driven property checks](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/generator_driven_property_checks). This type of tests is useful when you need to validate some properties, such as commutative property.

```scala
// Generator-driven property
forAll { (a: Int, b: Int) =>
  (a + b) should be(b + a)
}

forAll { (a: Int, b: Int) =>
  whenever(a != b && (a != 0 || b != 0)) {
    (a - b) should not be(b - a)
  }
}
```

---

Table-driven and Generator-driven property checks comes from [Property-based testing](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/property_based_testing).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed answer above! The clarification on the semantics of Table-driven property checks is useful. I figured out how to achieve what I was after though. I need to create a new table by using the expanded output of the zip with map as the contents of that table, like so:

```
val inputsWithExpectedValues = Table(
  // header of new table
  ("a", "b", "addition", "subtraction"),
  // new rows of table
  inputs
    .zip(expectedOutputs)
    .map({
      // flatten out component columns
      case ((a, b), (addition, subtraction)) =>
        (a, b, addition, subtraction)
    }): _*
)
```

Comment: I don't think that is a good approach. Having a collection with the inputs and another one with the outputs could be hard to maintain if both of them start getting bigger and bigger. Also remember that the `zip` method will truncate the larger list if they have different sizes.